# how to check internet connection status without any site dependency in batch script?

Tags: batch

Currently i've this script, but in some countries sites like google are blocked so this script is not universally applicable.

Question is,
Is it possible in batch script to know the status of internet connection without any site dependency?

```
@echo off  
ping www.google.com -n 1 -w 5000 > nul && (  
echo Internet is Connected.  
) || (  
echo Internet is not Connected.  
)  
pause
```

Comment: You can measure speed between to points, one is your device and something else on the internet, can't go without it. So the question is to find a website (IP address) what is available from everywhere. I'm not sure such exists. You can investigate address only as far as your router / modem, but measuring speed to that isn't measuring the speed of internet.

Comment: It depends on what you are considering as an "internet connection". If you want to check that you can reach some remote site then you should have some address of it. If you just want to check that the connection is exist then you could check a WAN interface status.

Comment: Most countries block the hostname, not the IP, so you could ping 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 or the IP of any predetermined "reliable" destination.